# Requests POI from a location using Xamarin (Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, location, google-places-api

Im trying to create an android app with xamarin.I want the user to be able to input an address/location and receive POI (Points of Interest) near it (within a certain radius).

I know google places api can do this, does xamarin have built in capability for something like this? Can I somehow interface with the Google Places api?

Or is there something I don't know about? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HTTPWebRequest class to create a request to Google API, code snippet:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=7500&types=library&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyD3jfeMZK1SWfRFDgMfxn_zrGRSjE7S8Vg") as HttpWebRequest;
  webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
  webRequest.Method = "GET";

  webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RequestCompleted), webRequest);
}

private void RequestCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
  var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
  using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
  {
    var r = new StreamReader(stream);
    var resp = r.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```

copy over from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8f0f96f4-9afb-4d78-a595-f7d7b6e1e4ff/google-places-api-and-c?forum=winforms)... pretty straightforward and simple...