# Populating a map with near by places in xamarin android using Place API

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to populate a google map with user's near by places like Hotels, Restaurants etc..
Unfortunately i am unable to find a support for xamarin android and place API in xamarin android
Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: Use the places web API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087675/requests-poi-from-a-location-using-xamarin-android

Comment: You would use the code in the answer there, and substitute the URL with the one in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161395/im-trying-to-search-nearby-places-such-as-banks-restaurants-atms-inside-the-d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Places` nuget:

```
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Places" version="32.940.0-beta3" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
```

Once added to your `Xamarin.Android` project, you can add the Place APIs to your `GoogleApiClient`:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
.Builder(this)
.AddApi(PlacesClass.GEO_DATA_API)
.AddApi(PlacesClass.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
.EnableAutoManage(this, this)
.Build();
```

The Places APIs are in the `Android.Gms.Location.Places` namespace.

Comment: That seems to be a solution, I am new in xamarin Android can you tell me how to use this. Using the above code
.EnableAutoManage(this, this)    gives  the redline error that says cannot convert from App4 to Android .Support,V4.AppFragment Activity and cannot convert from App4 to System.Android<Android,Gms.Common.ConnectionResult> these two red underline errors appears under (this,this) respectively

Comment: Got here after upgrading Xamarin.GooglePlayServices package and needed to add the nuget package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Places for the PlacesClass class.